# Task.Run does unexpected things

Tags: vb.net, task

I'm stumped... I'm trying to get the hang of splitting up calculations in tasks to speed up the program. That seems to work fine for small pieces of code, but I'm failing miserably when it gets a little more difficult.

Situation:
I have a program that calculates about 1,000 factors in a 5-step process for each factor. I want to split the calculation of those factors up into tasks.

The code that does the trick (but without using Tasks):

```
Public Overridable Function GetFactor(Gender As Short, Age As Short) As Double Implements IFactor.GetFactor
    'Set up the Markov Chain associated with a factor
    Me.Markov = New MarkovChain(Gender, Age)

    'Set up the payment schedule
    Me.Payments = New PaymentsAnnuity(Age, Me.MaxAge)

    'Determine the benefits
    Me.Benefits = New Benefit(Age, Me.MaxAge)

    'Calculate the cash flows
    Call Me.CalcCashFlow()

    'Calculate the factor and return it
    Return Me.CalcFactor()
End Function
```

That code works fine for one factor. I then have a calculation engine that iterates through all factors and ages

```
Public Sub RunCalculations(ByVal MinAge As Short, ByVal MaxAge As Short)
    'Cycle through all available factors
    For iParam As Integer = 0 To Me.Factors.Length - 1
        'Fetch the new factor specific parameter set
        Dim Param As FactorParameters = Me.Factors(iParam)

        'Get a new factor generator of the proper kind. Note that all generators are stored in their corresponding
        'FactorParameters "FactorType" value upon creation of the Calculation Engine to allow for easy selection
        Dim Generator As IFactor = Me.Generators(Param.FactorType).GetInstance(Me.Assumptions, Param)

        'Calculate the factors for both males and females and store them in the Output matrices
        For iAge As Short = MinAge To MaxAge
            Me.OutputResultsMale(iAge - MinAge, iParam + 1) = Generator.GetFactor(0, iAge)
            Me.OutputResultsFemale(iAge - MinAge, iParam + 1) = Generator.GetFactor(1, iAge)
        Next iAge
    Next iParam
End Sub
```

The above code runs fine and I get all the factors I asked for, but it takes ages. I therefore tried to generate tasks, one for each factor and have it run on multiple cores. I changed the code in the Sub RunCalculations (most notably the iAge For-loop):

```
Public Sub RunCalculations(ByVal MinAge As Short, ByVal MaxAge As Short)
    'Set up Task matrices to populate the output matrices
    Dim aTasksMale(MaxAge - MinAge, Me.Factors.Length) As Task(Of Double)
    Dim aTasksFemale(MaxAge - MinAge, Me.Factors.Length) As Task(Of Double)

    'Cycle through all available factors
    For iParam As Integer = 0 To Me.Factors.Length - 1
        'Fetch the new factor specific parameter set
        Dim Param As FactorParameters = Me.Factors(iParam)

        'Get a new factor generator of the proper kind. Note that all generators are stored in their corresponding
        'FactorParameters "FactorType" value upon creation of the Calculation Engine to allow for easy selection
        Dim Generator As IFactor = Me.Generators(Param.FactorType).GetInstance(Me.Assumptions, Param)

        'Calculate the factors for both males and females and store them in the Task matrices
        For iAge As Short = MinAge To MaxAge
            'Set up a local variable and set it to the iteration value
            'Note: not doing this results in the following Warning: "Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.
            'Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable."
            Dim iLoopAge As Short = iAge

            'Run the tasks of generating the factors for both males and females
            aTasksMale(iLoopAge - MinAge, iParam + 1) = Task.Run(Function() Generator.GetFactor(0, iLoopAge))
            aTasksFemale(iLoopAge - MinAge, iParam + 1) = Task.Run(Function() Generator.GetFactor(1, iLoopAge))
        Next iAge
    Next iParam

    'Wait for all tasks to complete
    Task.WaitAll()

    'Populate the output matrices
    For iAge = MinAge To MaxAge
        For iFactor = 1 To Me.Factors.Length
            'Copy the factors to the output matrices
            Me.OutputResultsMale(iAge - MinAge, iFactor) = aTasksMale(iAge - MinAge, iFactor).Result
            Me.OutputResultsFemale(iAge - MinAge, iFactor) = aTasksFemale(iAge - MinAge, iFactor).Result
        Next iFactor
    Next iAge
End Sub
```

I was hoping (and perhaps even expecting) that would do the trick and speed up the process, but instead I get a weird error I can't seem to fix, especially in the CalcCashFlow and CalcFactor routines. The CalcFactor routine is pretty short and simple:

```
    Friend Overridable Function CalcFactor() As Double
    'Set up a double representing the factor
    Dim dFactor As Double

    'Cycle through all cash flows
    For iPeriod As Short = 0 To Me.CashFlow.Length - 1
        'Determine the present value of the cash flow and add it to the factor value
        dFactor += Me.CashFlow(iPeriod) * Me.Assumptions.Yield.GetPV(iPeriod)
    Next iPeriod

    'Return the factor
    Return dFactor
End Function
```

I get an IndexOutOfBounds error for the iPeriod loop variable in the CalcFactor routine. When I get the OutOfBounds error I noticed that the iPeriod variable would be (e.g.) 118 whereas the cash flow array holds only 113 values (the values for both the iPeriod variable and the length of the Factor array differ between runs / errors). I don't understand why, because the loop explicitly says iPeriod should only loop until the end of the cash flow array.
When running the 'regular' (slow) program, iPeriod would never get above 113 in that example. But adding it to a Task somehow screws that all up. It looks like the iPeriod loop variable gets mixed up with other tasks or something, so I also tried adding a new local looping variable and setting it to the iPeriod variable, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here?
If you need more explanation / code, just let me know.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Parallel programming in .NET: A guide to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/) and [Data Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library?source=recommendations).

Comment: I would recommend some combination of breakpoints and debug writes to inspect what's happening with your code.  If you're worried about timing, you can use e.g. `Task.Delay` to introduce arbitrary delays on certain code paths to ensure that other things happen first.

Comment: It's not your immediate problem, but `Task.WaitAll()` doesn't make any sense (in fact, I wouldn't even expect it to compile).  It should receive an array of tasks, and it will then block until all of the tasks in the provided array are complete.

Comment: Thanks both, your suggestions were both helpful. Debugging with tasks seems to be a lot harder than without them, but it paid off :). All I really had to do was stop using one Generator for two simultaneous tasks. When I put the Task in a separate function which always instantiates a new Generator for each calculation, it finally worked. 
I also changed the Task.WaitAll bit to be actually useful by feeding it all the tasks as a parameter. Although Task.WaitAll() does compile, it apparently doesn't do much... Thanks for that tip as well!

Comment: Please, in future, post a [mcve], as it's impossible to post correct answers without being able to run your code. And, also, what you have posted as an answer - `GenerateFactorAsync` - doesn't make sense as it's not an `Async` function. All I can say is that your code looks quite fragile and I feel that it could be refactored to be much stronger, but it's so incomplete I wouldn't wasn't to hazard a guess what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the help of commenters: I used one class instance (Generator) for two simultaneous tasks, which .Net apparently did not appreciate. Changed part of the RunCalculations code to reflect that and added a separate function that always instantiates a new Generator for each calculation:

```
    'Set up Task lists to populate the output matrices
    Dim TaskListMale As New List(Of Task(Of Double))
    Dim TaskListFemale As New List(Of Task(Of Double))
    Dim NextTask As Task(Of Double)

    'Cycle through all available factors
    For iParam As Short = 0 To Me.Factors.Length - 1
        'Fetch the next factor specific parameter set
        Dim Param As FactorParameters = Me.Factors(iParam)

        'Set up the tasks
        For iAge As Short = MinAge To MaxAge
            'Set up a local variable and set it to the iteration value
            'Note: not doing this results in the following Warning: "Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.
            'Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable."
            Dim iLoopAge As Short = iAge

            'Calculate the factors for both males and females and add them to the Task lists
            NextTask = Task.Run(Function() GenerateFactorAsync(Param, Gender.Male, iLoopAge))
            TaskListMale.Add(NextTask)
            NextTask = Task.Run(Function() GenerateFactorAsync(Param, Gender.Female, iLoopAge))
            TaskListFemale.Add(NextTask)
        Next iAge
    Next iParam

    'Wait for all tasks to complete
    Task.WaitAll(TaskListMale.ToArray)
    Task.WaitAll(TaskListFemale.ToArray)

    'Populate the output matrices from the task lists. For easier reference, a counter variable is used
    Dim iTask As Short = 0
    For iFactor = 0 To Me.Factors.Length - 1
        For iAge = MinAge To MaxAge
            'Copy the factors to the output matrices
            Me.OutputResultsMale(iAge - MinAge, iFactor + 1) = TaskListMale(iTask).Result
            Me.OutputResultsFemale(iAge - MinAge, iFactor + 1) = TaskListFemale(iTask).Result
            iTask += 1
        Next iAge
    Next iFactor
End Sub

Private Function GenerateFactorAsync(ByVal Param As FactorParameters, ByVal Gender As Gender, ByVal Age As Short) As Double
    'Get a new factor generator of the proper kind. Note that all generators are stored in their corresponding
    'FactorParameters "FactorType" value upon creation of the Calculation Engine to allow for easy selection
    Dim Generator As IFactor = Me.Generators(Param.FactorType).GetInstance(Me.Assumptions, Param)

    'Calculate the corresponding factor for the gender and age given and return it
    Return Generator.GetFactor(Gender.Type, Age)
End Function
```

It now works as intended